# Redirect with cname to subdomain while retaining cname web address

Tags: redirect, cname

i have this problem where i have a subdomain sub.host.com and a new domain www.new.com. I want to redirect www.new.com to sub.host.com without showing the browser that the url had changed. The content is in sub.host.com but i want that even after the page has fully loaded, it is still showing www.new.com

This means also that when i go to sub.host.com/function, it should also appear as www.new.com/function

The reason is the actual subdomain looks ugly and contains numerics. Is this possible to do? Ive tried searching but all that comes up are only about how to go about creating cname records and none about keeping it intact after redirecting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A (reverse proxy) server like Nginx, which is very light-weight, features the url-rewrite rules that you need. IIS7 has also a good url-rewrite engine.